# Is it possible to zip and unzip the file in online through the programmatically in android

Tags: android

Need to convert file to zip file. Don't want to zip the file in my own application. I want to send the file to some third party url. Are they convert file into zip file and send back to me. Any third party is doing like that? If yes. Is this possible in android?
Please do me a favour.

Comment: Sounds like a **nonsense**. Why should you send out an uncompressed file, wait for compression and re get it? You can compress it by yourself on Android...

Comment: I think you still would be better on compressing it yourself on an Android device. I think it would take more time to send the uncompressed file to a service, and then receive them from the service afterwards. Thinking of battery usage, I would think the local compression would still be better..

Comment: And you don't need: 1 - an active connection, 2 - waiting for upload,compression,download times...

Comment: @ ndsmyter  Local compression is better than which i asked. I knew that it will take time to send the file, compression time and downloading time. Above task is given by senior. Need solution dude.

Comment: <http://www.zamzar.com/faq.php#Q44> Please check it. If we send the file to them. They will convert the file and send back to us through the email. But i need through the service.